# Custom CSS Cursor Goes Away When Clicking and Dragging and Becomes I-Bar

Tags: html, css, cursor

http://jsfiddle.net/QKJfW/

I want the cursor to remain the `cursor:move;` cursor even when clicking and dragging on the page.  As you can see now you get an i-bar like you are trying to select text.

In my real app it is actually a custom cursor.

Is that a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put these styles on the thing you want to be non selectable:

http://jsfiddle.net/QKJfW/1/

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

That should take care of your issue.

See: [How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Comment: He didn't say he didn't want the item select able...said he wanted to have the cursor remain regardless of mouse input.

Comment: This will actually work for my purposes.  But Jared is right, is there a way to keep my cursor or change the I-Bar?